# How To Bypass Folders Display And Go Straight To Photos Display By Using Android's INTENT Class?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, photo

I want my app to list/display only the phone's photos ( nothing else ) so that the user could select one of them whose bitmap will then be dealt later on by my remaining code.

The problem is that the code below instead of displaying photos directly, it first displays TWO FOLDERS ( Photos and Camera ) where photos are stored/grouped and waits for selection. How to bypass folders display/selection and go straight to photos display/selection ?
Here is the current code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want my app to list/display only the phone's photos ( nothing else )

Query the `MediaStore` to find images and handle the UI yourself.

> The problem is that the code below instead of displaying photos directly, it first displays TWO FOLDERS ( Photos and Camera )

It does that on your device. The results on other devices will vary, and there are ~2 billion of them, spread over ~20,000 device models. You are delegating to an indeterminate third-party app, which will vary by device and by user. It may result in a chooser for the user to select one of several apps that can handle your `Intent`.

If you do not like that behavior, query the `MediaStore` to find images and handle the UI yourself. This is more work, but you have complete control over the UI.

Comment: Can you suggest a simple code that gives a complete control over the UI for this case?

Comment: @BlueCrystal: There are dozens of existing libraries: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created. Perhaps one will fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, CommonsWare. I wonder if it will be legal to incorporate a piece of code from these libraries in my commercial ( monetizable ) app. Are there some legal restrictions or even an impossibility to do that ?

Comment: @BlueCrystal: The libraries in the Android Arsenal mostly are open source. Beyond that, please talk about software licenses with your attorney.

Comment: it is the first android app I am developing and I cannot afford to have an attorney. A quick reading on some of these open source ( free ? ) codes gave me the information that they want the interested person to obtain a license. A am not familiar with the legal jargon but it seems that such a license should be paid for, which is confusing to me. How the author of a supposed free code is asking money for his license ?